# Add custom wms layer to codename one Mapcontainer

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, codenameone, wms

I am building an android GPS app with Codename one. I use `com.codename1.googlemaps.MapContainer` to create a Google map;
In my app is use tabs to create different "pages".

Code:

```
cnt = new MapContainer();
t.addTab("Tab3", cnt);
```

And for my current location I use:

```
try {
  Coord position = new Coord(lat,lng);
  cnt.clearMapLayers();
  cnt.setCameraPosition(position);
  cnt.addMarker(EncodedImage.create("/maps-pin.png"), position, "Hi marker", "Optional long description", new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      // stuff todo...
    }
  });
} catch(IOException err) {
  // since the image is iin the jar this is unlikely
  err.printStackTrace();
}
```

I like to add a wms layer to the Google Maps. Is this possible? I can't find in codenameone a command `addLayer`. If yes, do you have a code snippet how to do this?
If it is not possiple, can I use openlayers in my codename one app? Can you give me a code snippet to do this?

**Edit**
I started to create an native file to "catch"the addtileoverlay from google maps api. The layer I want to use is a xyz layer, so I think I can use a urltileprovider from the googlemap api

I made the native code for  the tileoverlay but the tileoverlay doesn't appear. Is it because i didn't get a link with the mapcontainer.
I am little bit stuck. I tried to build from scratch with the googmaps example but the mapcompnent is not anymore used.

```
package com.Bellproductions.TalkingGps;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.UrlTileProvider;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlayOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileProvider;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlay;
import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class SeamarksImpl  { 

private GoogleMap mapInstance;
private TileOverlay m;
  TileProvider provider;
public boolean isSupported() {
    return true;
}

public long addTilelayer (){

 final String URL_FORMAT = "http://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";



    AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

public void run() {


provider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {

@Override
    public  synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {

try {
            y = (1 << zoom) - y - 1;
            return new URL(String.format(Locale.US, URL_FORMAT, zoom, x, y ));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

}

TileOverlayOptions tileopt = new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(provider);


public void addlayer() {
m = mapInstance.addTileOverlay(tileopt);
}

};

}

});

long p = 1;

return p;}

}
```

My seamarks.java file has this code to bind with the native interface

```
import com.codename1.system.NativeInterface;

/**
 *
 * @author Hongerige Wolf
 */


public interface Seamarks extends NativeInterface {
  public void addTilelayer ();
}
```

In the mainactivity java file i have the statements

```
public Seamarks seamark;
public void init(Object context) {

  seamark = (Seamarks)NativeLookup.create(Seamarks.class);
}

public void start() { 
      seamark.addTilelayer();
}
```

**Update**
I created a new googlemaps.CN1lib. But the xyz layer is not showing on the googlemaps. I used native code tot use the Tileoverlay feature and tried to add tileoverlay in the same way as Markers. 
In the InternalNativeMapsImpl file i changed

```
 private void installListeners() {
    /*
    if (mapInstance == null) {
        view = null;
        System.out.println("Failed to get map instance, it seems google play services are not installed");
        return;
    }*/
    view.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mapInstance = googleMap;

TileProvider tileProvider;
    tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
    String tileLayer= "http://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/";
        @Override
        public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            // The moon tile coordinate system is reversed.  This is not normal.
            int reversedY = (1 << zoom) - y - 1;
            //String s = String.format(Locale.US, tileLayer , zoom, x, y);
            String s = tileLayer + "/" + zoom + "/" + x + "/" + reversedY + ".png";
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(s);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
            return url;
        }
    };

    mMoonTiles =  mapInstance.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));




            mapInstance.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    Long val = listeners.get(marker);
                    if (val != null) {
                        MapContainer.fireMarkerEvent(InternalNativeMapsImpl.this.mapId, val.longValue());
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            mapInstance.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                    MapContainer.fireMapChangeEvent(InternalNativeMapsImpl.this.mapId, (int) position.zoom, position.target.latitude, position.target.longitude);
                }
            });
            mapInstance.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                    Point p = mapInstance.getProjection().toScreenLocation(point);
                    MapContainer.fireTapEventStatic(InternalNativeMapsImpl.this.mapId, p.x, p.y);
                }
            });


            mapInstance.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

                public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                    Point p = mapInstance.getProjection().toScreenLocation(point);
                    MapContainer.fireLongPressEventStatic(InternalNativeMapsImpl.this.mapId, p.x, p.y);
                }
            });
            mapInstance.setMyLocationEnabled(showMyLocation);
            mapInstance.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(rotateGestureEnabled);
        }
    });

}
```

Secondly i added a addTilexyz method also in the same way as addMarkers

```
 public long addTilexyz(final String Turl) {
    uniqueIdCounter++;
    final long key = uniqueIdCounter;
```

AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

```
TileProvider tileProvider;
    tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
    // Tileurl = "http://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/";
        @Override
        public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            // The moon tile coordinate system is reversed.  This is not normal.
            int reversedY = (1 << zoom) - y - 1;
            String s = String.format(Locale.US, Turl , zoom, x, reversedY);

            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(s);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
            return url;
        }
    };

    mMoonTiles =  mapInstance.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));      

        }
        });

    return key;
}
```

In the InternalNativeMaps file i added te method

```
    public long addTilexyz(String Turl);
```

And in the Mapcontainer file i added

```
 public MapObject addTilexyz(String Turl) {
    if(internalNative != null) {
         MapObject o = new MapObject();
         Long key = internalNative.addTilexyz(Turl);
         o.mapKey = key;
         markers.add(o);
        return o;
    } else {

        }

        MapObject o = new MapObject();
        return o;
    }
```

I am puzzeled what is wrong with the code.  I wonder if the commands

```
Long key = internalNative.addTilexyz(Turl);

and 

mMoonTiles =  mapInstance.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));
```

put the tileoverlay on the googlemap. Or is the tileurl wrong.  http://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/z/x/y.png is correct.

Answer (score 0):

We don't expose layers in the native maps at this time, you can [fork the project](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/) and just add an API to support that to the native implementations.

Comment: Thanks , I looked at the googlemap files but i can't figure out how i can appeend a wms layer tot the project. In the googlemap project is no reference to a wms layer. Or did I overlooked it

Comment: No there is none. You need to do this in the native implementation and add an API for that. Look at how we add markers and then do something similar to map the native WMS functionality upwards.

Comment: Ok i'll try. I use in my app addLongpresslistner, but in the googlemaps files there is no code for it.  In googlemaptest is the function compiled i suppose. How can i add this to the googlemaps code.

Comment: Notice the Google maps code already contains code for pointer handling since the pointer handling happens within the native layer. So you can just follow the lead of that listener call

Comment: I made the native code for the tileoverlay but the tileoverlay doesn't appear on the map. Is it because i didn't get a link with the mapcontainer.
I am little bit stuck. I tried to build from scratch with the googmaps example but the mapcompnent is not anymore used.

Comment: It's unclear how you bound it to the existing native interface, you do test it on the device right?

Comment: I teted on a android device

Comment: I tested it on a android device I update the edit above with the code how i bound to the native interface. I  have the feeling that the mapcontainer and the addtileoverlay command are nog binded tot the same object.

Comment: I would suggest removing the cn1lib. Copying it's source into your project and hacking the native interface directly. Once you have what you want with a proper API just copy it back into the cn1lib source and submit a pull request so everyone can enjoy that change...

Comment: Thanx, i tried before to change the googlemaps cn1ib but i dont't know how to connect to the InternalNativeMaps

Comment: Thanx, i tried before to change the googlemaps cn1ib but i dont't know how to connect to the InternalNativeMaps i got a error message it's a duplicate class. I tried to delete the file  InternalNativeMaps.java in the src directory but that doen't help. Ideas?

Comment: You need to add your methods into the internal native maps methods then edit the respective native implementations. To get the syntax for each OS just generate a standalone native interface in a separate project and copy the code from there....

Comment: Thanks again . I think i wasnt clear .  I tried to work with the googlemaps cn1lib github project. My problem is that in the mapcontainer file  the internalnativemap variabele is striked  through

Comment: Private InternalNativeMap  internalnativemaps is deprecated. I dont know how to call in a another way this variable.

Comment: You need to edit the implementation of the cn1lib. We deprecated this in the implementation so people don't use it and use the official API. If you edit the implementation you need to use it. Unfortunately Java doesn't provide us with refined deprecation to explain that "X" is an implementation detail but this is mentioned in the deprecation notes.

Comment: What do you mean with "edit the implementation of the cn1lib" is this a file inthe googlemaps cn1lib github directories or in the cn1lib sourcedode?

Comment: It's in the cn1lib source code which is in the github repository of the cn1lib. You can download the cn1lib and edit/work on it, you can copy it's entire source to your app directories (and delete the cn1lib to avoid conflict) modify it and then after you are done modifying it return the code back to the cn1lib to submit a pull request...

Comment: Thanks i'm on the good track . i have some problems with addlongrpresslistner  in the googmaptest directories     there is the code  cnt.addLongPressListener(new ActionListener())  But i can't find in the mapcontainerfile in the googlemaps directory such command. What is the code to addLongPressListener to the mapconainter file

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Long press listener is a feature of component not a feature of the native maps. The native maps have a tap listener

Comment: In the googlemap test github is long press added to the mapcontainer see [link] [https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps] buti can't find the code for the feature in the mapcontainer file

Comment: That's an API of `Container` I think it's a mistake in the test. The tap listener should be used...